# GA4 exploration - Manually sort columns?

Tags: graph, google-analytics, visualization, google-analytics-4

Ive been having troubles sorting my free form explorations data to the order I am wanting.

Here I want the video_complete row to be at the bottom of my nested list so it makes sense when reading this data:
How would you go about this? Im interested in any tips for sorting rows of data
[image]

Comment: Submitting as a comment instead of an answer, since it won't help achieve what you want, but may help others with the same question. One can sort a column by pressing the column name. In this case, you would press **Video Progress** at the top of your table. However, we can see the table is already sorted the way you want in theory. Google Analytics is just treating the numbers as strings, so `100` < `25`.